# Concating 2 lists with third list containing every different order of the elements of the 2 lists

Tags: list, prolog

So I have 2 lists and when concatenated it should return a list like shown below

**| ?- concat([a,b,c],[1,2,3,4],X).**

**X = [a,b,c,1,2,3,4] ;**

**X = [a,b,1,c,2,3,4] ;**

**X = [a,b,1,2,c,3,4] ;**

**X = [a,b,1,2,3,c,4] ;**

**X = [a,b,1,2,3,4,c] ;**

**...**

So I wrote this code to answer the question:

```
concat([], Y, Y).
concat([E|X], Y, [E|Z]) :- concat(X,Y,Z).
   concat(X, Y, [Y|X]).
```

But I get this as an output

**?- concat([a,b,c],[1,2,3,4],X).**

**X = [a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, 4] ;**

**X = [a, b, c, [1, 2, 3, 4]] ;**

**X = [a, b, [1, 2, 3, 4], c] ;**

**X = [a, [1, 2, 3, 4], b, c] ;**

**X = [[1, 2, 3, 4], a, b, c].**

I'm new to Prolog so I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the 3rd line:

```
concat(X, Y, [Y|X]).
```

`[Y|X]` is not a list of all the elements of `Y` followed by all the elements of `X`, it is a list whose first element is the list `Y` and then the rest of the elements are the elements of X.

My code below works as follows:

```
concat([], [], []).
concat([E|X], Y, [E|Z]) :- concat(X,Y,Z).
concat(X, [F|Y], [F|Z]) :- concat(X,Y,Z).
```

The first line that you had `concat([], Y, Y).` works fine but I think my way is neater and more symmetric as a base case for the induction.

Comment: Thanks for this, I see where I went wrong now. It also helped me with other things that I was trying.